# Javascript onclick Dropdown menu not shown after adding another div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a Dropdown menu **onclick** with Javascript. The dropdown menu is worked but there I face a problem. I also added a shadow in my Dropdown Menu. The shadow is not shown when I give another div element after the Dropdown Menu. See the image below -

If I add ***"position:relative"*** in my CSS code ***".navbar"*** class, it works. But that time the Dropdown Menu is not shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        *
        {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
        }
        body
        {
            padding: 0;
        }
        .navbar
        {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
            overflow: hidden;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
            z-index: 4;
            position: relative;
        }
        .navbar a
        {
            padding:15px 0px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            float: left;
            font-weight: 200;
        }
        .dropbtn
        {
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            padding: 21.5px 20px;
            background-color: inherit;
            margin: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bolder;
            color: #2d3436;
        }
        .dropbtn:hover,.dropbtn:focus i
        {
            color: #01ad6e;
        }
        .dropdown 
        {
            float: left;
        }
        .dropdown-content 
        {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #fff;
            min-width: 460px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
            height: 450px;
            border-radius: 3.5px;
            z-index: 1;
            border-top: 2px solid #000;
        }
        .show{display:block}
        .container
        {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 2% 20% 2% 20%;
            background-color: #dfe4ea;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="navbar">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="my2Function()" class="dropbtn dropbtn1">Marketing</button>
            <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content dropdown-content1">
              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="my2Function()" class="dropbtn dropbtn2">Development</button>
            <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content dropdown-content2">
              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="my3Function()" class="dropbtn dropbtn3">Others</button>
            <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content dropdown-content2">
              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Marketing</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
    function my1Function() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    function my2Function() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    function my3Function() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown3").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

      const dropdownContents = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content')
      dropdownContents.forEach(content => {
        content.classList.remove('show');
      });

      if (event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
      }
    })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you attach any picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the navbar CSS to

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
    height: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
  }
```

We need to remove the `overflow: hidden` and add height to navbar. Overflow hidden will hide the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

There was multiple error/mistake. I have change the code and looks it's working.

Changes are:

1. `.navbar{overflow: hidden;}` Remove the property from `.navbar`.
2. First onclick event should call `my1Function()` but you did `my2Function()`
3. Comment the last addEventListener is script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        *
        {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
        }
        body
        {
            padding: 0;
        }
        .navbar
        {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
            z-index: 4;
            position: relative;
        }
        .navbar a
        {
            padding:15px 0px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            float: left;
            font-weight: 200;
        }
        .dropbtn
        {
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            padding: 21.5px 20px;
            background-color: inherit;
            margin: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bolder;
            color: #2d3436;
        }
        .dropbtn:hover,.dropbtn:focus i
        {
            color: #01ad6e;
        }
        .dropdown 
        {
            float: left;
        }
        .dropdown-content 
        {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #fff;
            min-width: 460px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
            height: 450px;
            border-radius: 3.5px;
            z-index: 1;
            border-top: 2px solid #000;
        }
        .show{display:block}
        .container
        {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 2% 20% 2% 20%;
            background-color: #dfe4ea;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="navbar">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="my1Function()" class="dropbtn dropbtn1">Marketing</button>
            <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content dropdown-content1">
              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="my2Function()" class="dropbtn dropbtn2">Development</button>
            <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content dropdown-content2">
              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="my3Function()" class="dropbtn dropbtn3">Others</button>
            <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content dropdown-content2">
              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Marketing</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
    function my1Function() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    function my2Function() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    function my3Function() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown3").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    /* window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

      const dropdownContents = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content')
      dropdownContents.forEach(content => {
        content.classList.remove('show');
      });

      if (event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
      }
    }) */
    </script>
</body>
```